# How are the payment events attached to standalone PayPal button in the JS SDK versus rendering all available payment buttons?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am transitioning from the simple paypal buttons that had the copy-and-paste code with the multiple screens in which the taxes and shipping options could be configure for each button to their [JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/).  I have it working in the sandbox so long as the `paypal.Buttons({...}).render('#paypal-button-container');` setup is used to display all the available payment buttons.  This is all on the client; not processing it from the server.

When I try to employ the method to limit the funding sources as described in the these  paypal [instructions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/standalone-buttons), the correct buttons are rendered but they are no longer connected to the events.  Every tests purchase in the sandbox is for one penny only.  If the code is returned to render all the paypal buttons, it all works fine.

I'm sure it's a stupid question because I'm using the same `paypal.Buttons({...}).render('#paypal-button-container');` method except without the `.render('#paypal-button-container')` and then adding the code below.

Would you please explain how to get the event code added when each button is in `FUNDING_SOURCES` array is processed separately?  I'm attempting only two: `[paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL, paypal.FUNDING.CARD].forEach( function (fundingSource) {...`

Thank you.  By the way, I know that paypal recommended showing every available funding option but there is only one product and it is very nominally priced; so, the deferred payment options are a bit ridiculous in this case.  Thank you.

```
// Loop over each funding source/payment method

FUNDING_SOURCES.forEach(function(fundingSource) {
    // Initialize the buttons
    var button = paypal.Buttons({
        fundingSource: fundingSource
    });

    // Check if the button is eligible
    if (button.isEligible()) {
        // Render the standalone button for that funding source
        button.render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your issue correctly. Otherwise please rephrase...

**Instead of looping through the options, your best shot is enabling what you need / disabling what you don't need in the script initialization.**

See https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/

All parameters are listed under "[query parameters](https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#query-parameters)".

What you need is `disable-funding` / `enable-funding`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Using query parameters is much simpler than those instructions I was reading for funding standalone buttons.  Perhaps, I was looking at the sever-side approach but it appeared to be for the client-side JS SDK.

Comment: Can you link to the stand alone button docs you were reading through?

Comment: The link in the question labeled `instructions` is for stand alone buttons.  I accidentally included a page anchor in the link that made that confusing.  I've correct it so it loads at the top of the page.

Comment: Didn't realize you where talking about the standalone examples. Sorry for that. You pretty much follow what's recommended there.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK line `disable-funding` can be used, as the other answer mentions, but it's always possible for something not explicitly disabled to appear as one of the buttons, if you don't use standalone buttons.

True standalone buttons means specifying a fundingSource explicitly, which is this section of the code in your question.

```
    paypal.Buttons({
        fundingSource: fundingSource
    });
```

Now to your issue: that very section is what needs to be expanded in order to "connect the button to events" -- basically you need a createOrder and onApprove in there, as well as any other JSDK callbacks you want that button to use; otherwise you're just getting the default 0.01 demo behavior for the button.

For a full example of all the code that should go inside that `paypal.Buttons` call, see https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server (server or client-only versions)

---

Anyway, more specific to your use case:

> By the way, I know that paypal recommended showing every available funding option but there is only one product and it is very nominally priced; so, the deferred payment options are a bit ridiculous in this case. Thank you.

If all you really want to accomplish is to disable Pay Later and PayPal Credit, `&disable-funding=credit` is sufficient and you don't need to render standalone buttons.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  The method for standalone buttons, I assume, is like adding event listeners to each individual button rather than to a parent container.  So, I could just move all the event code that worked earlier into the forEach loop.  For now, in this simple case, I used `enable-funding` and chose the two desired: paypal and card.  Thanks again.

Comment: More specifically, standalone buttons means to render each button individually / independently (it's in the name, standalone). Each time you render a button you have to give it a `createOrder` + `onApprove` etc callback function. If you don't specify these callback functions each time you invoke `paypal.Buttons` , then all such buttons will do is the 0.01 demo behavior, because they have no way to create an order for anything else.

Comment: Preston PHX is right. It's worth checking the available callbacks in detail BTW. It's recommended to implement the `cancel` and `error` callback  as well.